# How does bindView work?

Tags: android

I have a custom CursorAdapter. I have overridden bindView method as

```
public void bindView(View view,Context context, Cursor cursor){
       TextView title=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_title);
       title.setText(cursor.getString(1));
       TextView subTitle=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_subtitle);
       subTitle.setText(cursor.getString(2));
}
```

My question is that while generating new list item how does the new list item contain elements from the next row of the cursor? Is cursor.moveToNext() automatically called?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, quoting the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#bindView%28android.view.View,%20android.content.Context,%20android.database.Cursor%29) (emphasis mine):

> cursor    The cursor from which to get the data. **The cursor is already moved to the correct position.**